# How to create a loop that pastes onto the end of the iteration of the loop in R

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I am trying to write loop that creates a character vector. I would like each element to copy the last element whilst adding more string. For example:

```
f <- "y ~ x1" "y ~ x1 + x2" "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3" "y ~ x1 + ... + x100"
```

So far, I have:

```
f <- character(100)
for(i in 1:100){
  f[i] <- paste0("y ~ x1 +",i) 
}
```

[1] "y ~ x1 +1"   "y ~ x1 +2"   "y ~ x1 +3"   "y ~ x1 +4"

But cannot work out how to combine each of the last iteration with each of the new ones.
Any help appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. You can combine two `paste0()` ad use the index in the loop to create the formulas in a smart way. Here the code:

```
#Code
f <- character(100)
#Loop
for(i in 1:100){
  f[i] <- paste0("y ~ ",paste0("x",1:i,collapse = ' + ')) 
}
```

Output (Only some values):

```
head(f)
[1] "y ~ x1"                          "y ~ x1 + x2"                    
[3] "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3"                "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4"          
[5] "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5"      "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6"
```

Or a simplified version with `lapply()`:

```
#Code2
f <- lapply(1:100,function(i) paste0("y ~ ",paste0("x",1:i,collapse = ' + ')) )
```

It will produce same output.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @annie100 A pleasure, I also added a version without loop if you feel more curious about other methods to reach same output.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `reformulate` from `base R`

```
lapply(1:5, function(i) reformulate(paste0("x", 1:i), "y"))
```